# Python. Iterate over a list of files, finding same filenames but different extensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

So I have a list as follows:

`mylist = ['movie1.mp4','movie2.srt','movie1.srt','movie3.mp4','movie1.mp4']`

Note: a simple list for testing, the script will deal with unknown file names and more of them.

So I want to find the movie files with a paired srt file, and put those in a dictionary. Anything left (ie movie3.mp4) will be left in the list and dealt with later.

I've been playing a bit with list comprehension, though it might not leave the leftover data and allow me to construct the dictionary.

`import re
 matches = [ x for x, a in mylist if (re.sub('\.srt$', '\.mp4$', a ) == x or     re.sub('\.srt$', '\.mp4$', a ) == x) ]`

This returns:
`ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Any ideas on how I might approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adopting a wrong approach to your problem. The easiest would be to determine the basenames of the files using [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) and group them according to it. A possible approach would be to use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

**Implementation**

```
groups = {key: set(value)
      for key, value in groupby(sorted(mylist,
                                       key = lambda e: os.path.splitext(e)[0]),
                                key = lambda e: os.path.splitext(e)[0])}
```

**Example**

```
>>> pprint.pprint(groups)
{'movie1': set(['movie1.mp4', 'movie1.srt']),
 'movie2': set(['movie2.srt']),
 'movie3': set(['movie3.mp4'])}
```

Comment: That works quite nicely. I hadn't used os.path.splitext before; very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the task into to separate concerns: first build dictionary, grouping files with the same rootname; later check which have both video and subtitle file. (And please don't use regex to split filenames, `os.path` does much better here).

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os

mylist = ['movie1.mp4','movie2.srt','movie1.srt','movie3.mp4','movie1.mp4']

movies = defaultdict(dict)
for filename in mylist:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    movies[name][ext] = filename

sub_extentions = set(['.txt', '.srt'])
movie_extensions = set(['.mp4', '.avi'])


for name, files in movies.items():
    files_set = set(files.keys())
    if not files_set & sub_extentions:
        continue # no subs
    elif not files_set & movie_extensions:
        continue # no movie
    else:
        print name, files.values()
# output: movie1 ['movie1.srt', 'movie1.mp4']
```

PS. What are you going to do with `.mkv` files with enclosed subtitles? ;)